# Field Labels Missing in LWC Display for External Objects After Installation in an Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-connect, externalobjects, external-lookup

We have 2 Orgs. One 'Global' and one 'Local'. The local is connected to global via SF Connect and has some of global org's objects as external objects.

In the local we have a LWC which acts a custom compact layout and is placed on a local case's (Case object) flexi page. To make the lwc dynamic we can give as inputs an object api name and fieldset name. The lwc calls the apex to retrieve the field labels from the given inputs.

On the HTML of lwc we use `lightning-record-view-form` and `lightning-output-field` to display the field labels and their values. The object and fieldset belong to external object (Case__x).

The problem is working on a scratch org we are able to see all field labels (Client's name has no value and is correct).

[image: Working in Scratch]

For the other orgs (local) we dont deploy but create a package and install them. Here we are having a problem. Sometimes we simple have a blank space (in the below pic. `Current Location Formula`  Label itself is missing).

[image: Not working]

The `Current Location Formula` is formula field that refers to a Lookup's Name field (Account's Name), hence a cross-object formula field. In the local org. `Current Location Formula` appears as `Long Text Area(1300)`

In the previous installations it was working. We have check per object and field permissions.

Why is the field itself missing in the org. where we installed? And how can we display it?